# Git - stash current commit to be added to current branch at a later date

Tags: git, github, version-control

I hope I'm explaining this well. I'm sure this has been answered, at least in fragments, but I'm unsure how to search for it and/or do this in the best way for my workflow. I'm also not totally sure what the ramifications are for using different methods.

### Situation

I have branched from master, into `feature-branch` and committed work `current-work` (but haven't pushed yet). I discovered, for workflow/reviewing reasons on my future pull request, that I should have committed `preliminary-automated-work` and `preliminary-cleanup-work` before `current-work`. And they must appear in that order on the branch named `feature-branch`.

### The Question

How should I stash/move/store/whatever `current-work` so that I can do `preliminary-automated-work` and `preliminary-cleanup-work` and commit those, in sequence, to `feature-branch` and then recover `current-work` and commit that to `feature-branch` after the previous preliminary commits?

Comment: `current-work` consists of many commits or is it only one you want to undo? if that's the case you can use `git reset --soft HEAD^` to undo the last commit and return the modified files to the staging area. from there you can add & commit `preliminary-cleanup-work` and `preliminary-automated-work` and then commit again `current-work`

Comment: `current-work` is a single commit. So you're recommending putting `current-work` back into staging, then doing the preliminary work and commit them by sidestepping the changes of `current-work`. Then commit the remaining changes, i.e. `current-work`. That might work for my situation, but what if one of the files in `current-work` overlapped with a file change in one of the preliminary commits?

Comment: Indeed I'm suggesting what you said. To answer your question, it depends: if you have a file `f` in staging area and you modify it again and add the modification; then when you commit `f` it will have both changes. Now, if changes for `f` are already committed and you modify `f`, add it and commit again, then the last version of `f` will be pushed (so be sure not to be losing any changes (which is not probable since you are probably changing code over the same version of `f`))

Comment: @odradek, if you want to submit your suggestion as an answer, I'd like to upvote it as I think it is a viable solution for some people with similar problems as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Create a temporary local branch, e.g. rename your `feature-branch`

   ```
   $ git branch -m temporary-branch
   ```
2. Checkout the `feature-branch` from the correct point in your history. Assuming it is only one commit:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b feature-branch HEAD~
   ```
3. Commit `preliminary-automated-work` and `preliminary-cleanup-work`
4. Check out `temporary-branch` (The `HEAD` commit should be `current-work`)
5. Rebase your `temporary-branch` onto `feature-branch`

   ```
   $ git rebase feature-branch
   ```
6. Fast-forward you `feature-branch` to the state of `temporary-branch`

   ```
   $ git checkout feature-branch
   Switched to branch 'feature-branch'
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature-branch' by 2 commits.
     (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
   $ git merge --ff-only temporary-branch
   ```
7. Delete your `temporary-branch` (after verifying everything is correct)

   ```
   $ git branch -D temporary-branch
   ```

The advantage of this is (imho) that at **no** point in time there is the possibilty to lose work (except maybe `git branch -D` :P)

Comment: This is the strategy I was considering. Thanks for assembling all the commands! I'm not sure I would have done them all correctly just winging it. I'll let other answers roll in but I think this is the one I'll accept. Thank you.